# When selecting an arcane school for the Arcanist's School Understanding Exploit can you choose a focused arcane school?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can an Arcanist that selects the [School Understanding Exploit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits/school-understanding/) choose one of the focused arcane schools available to Wizards? For instance the [Teleportation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/conjuration/teleportation/) school of Conjuration or the [Foresight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/divination/foresight/) school of Divination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

The text of the Arcanist's ability specifies (emphasis mine):

> The arcanist can select one arcane school from **any of the schools available** to a character with the arcane school wizard class feature

There is no caveat that limits the choices; it says any school a wizard could choose, the Arcanist can choose. Additionally, the Arcanist was published well after other materials that introduced most of these variant arcane school choices, so it is not a situation where the ability was written and the options it provides were expanded later; these were available choices when the Arcanist ability was written and the text specifies "any" rather than providing a list. Taken together, there's no rules-as-written reason that the Arcanist should not be able to choose these variant schools, nor does it appear that such a restriction was intended (quite the opposite).

Answer (score 1):

The [arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/) [exploit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/#TOC-Arcanist-Exploits) [school understanding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits/school-understanding/) says that an arcanist picks "one arcane school from any of the schools available to a character with the arcane school wizard class feature." So, in addition to being able to pick from the traditional schools like [abjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/abjuration/), an arcanist should also be able to pick from focused arcane schools like [foresight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/divination/foresight/) or even elemental schools like [void](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/elemental-arcane-schools/void-elemental-school/). However, the exploit school understanding *is* vague as to how it works with some school special abilities like the [divination](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/divination/) school supernatural ability forewarned, so ask the GM if picking something exceptionally wacky.

A *really* strict GM *could* forbid an arcanist from picking a focused arcane school or an elemental school by ruling that these are not, technically, arcane schools, in the same way that [cover](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Cover) is different from partial, total, and improved cover. But, seeing as how the arcanist is already *Pathfinder*'s most powerful class, that seems a particularly unusual ruling to make.